# Smart approach to CSS3

Tags: coding-style, cross-browser, css

do You have any elegant approach to benefit from CSS3 features, like border radius or gradients?

I am looking for a solution that would avoid browser-specific CSS properties and browser-specific stylesheet files. I find them both hard to maintain and too verbose.

It could be a Javascript library that would take care of cross-browser compatibilit. Thus, I could use only W3C CSS3 properties support (not browser-specific) and get rid of the library when browsers will start tu support CSS3 well.

So far, I have found these resources that seem to fulfill at least some of my expectations:

- **[eCSStender](http://ecsstender.org/)** - JS that is told to **imitate the CSS3 features on different browsers** (even IE6), I haven't tested yet, however ([read about eCSStender](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/stop-forking-with-css3/))
- **[Mordernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)** - JS that **detects which CSS3 properties the browser supports**
- ... *I'll fiil it with your answers*

**Or maybe you have other approach that lets You take advantage of CSS3 without very verbose code?**

Comment: A link regarding modernizr: [Taking Advantage of HTML5 and CSS3 with Modernizr](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which has a border-radius example on their homepage:

```
.rounded_corners (@radius: 5px) {
    -moz-border-radius: @radius;
    -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
    border-radius: @radius;
}
#header {
    .rounded_corners;
}
```

However, I really don't find it *that* messy to use browser prefixes. For a `border-radius`, the only thing you need is this:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
```

That will work in about a dozen browsers (if you include mobile browsers). Using indentation in this fashion also makes it easier not to forget to update one of the properties. When you decide do drop support for Safari 4 or whatever, you can simply search and replace the rules you want to remove from your CSS files.

Compare that to when we needed box model hacks, NS4, IE5/Mac fixes, and all of that crap.

Answer (score 0):

This is not CSS3 specific, but as you are asking for a concise way to handle the styles and do mention modernizr (which works by adding `classes` like `no-borderradius` to your `<html>` element if that feature is not available), I thought it might be helpful for a generally improved way to organize your CSS.

There is [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) that allows the use of variables, mixins or nested rules in CSS (see the link for examples). This however requires you to compile your .less files into valid .css. To avoid this, there is/will be [less.js](http://github.com/cloudhead/less.js) (see also: [Less.js Will Obsolete CSS](http://fadeyev.net/2010/06/19/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/)) which enables you to include .less files directly in your page (useful at least during development).

I think LESS does not require you to learn a lot of new syntax rules and might help to organize fallback CSS right next to the "real" style.

Comment: Thanks. LESS seems certainly interesting. BTW,I wish CSS supported variables, mixins or operations. However, lack of back compatibility with CSS is a big drawback to me.

Comment: LESS is compiled to regular CSS and you are free to use the produced CSS file instead of LESS at any point. It just helps organizing your CSS during development (and maintenance). Also, rename your .css file to .less and you have a valid LESS file. So it is easy to switch from one to another and back.